# How to center a group of search bars in html/css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get some search bars and submit buttons lined up, but I don't know how to do it. I know it's probably really simple, but I'm new to HTML. (Oh and this is only part of the browser, doesn't usually look as bad as this xD

```css
.center-block{
    margin-top: 220px;
    text-align: center;
}
.searchboxes{
    width: 500px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
.searchboxes:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.clickboxes{
    opacity: 0.6;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-top: 480px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
.clickboxes:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <img class="center-block" src="/assets/logo.png" alt="MsearchLogo" style="width:480px;height:270px;">

      <form id="vb_yt_search-form" action="https://duckduckgo.com/" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input name="q" type="text" maxlength="128" class="searchboxes" />
    <input type="submit" value="DuckDuckGo" class="clickboxes" />
      </form>
      <br />
  <form id="vb_yt_search-form" action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input name="q" type="text" maxlength="128" class="searchboxes" />
    <input type="submit" value="Google" class="clickboxes" />
  </form>
  <br />
<form id="vb_yt_search-form" action="http://www.youtube.com/results" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input id="vb_yt_search-term" name="search_query" type="text" maxlength="128" class="searchboxes" />
    <input type="submit" value="Youtube" class="clickboxes" />
 </a>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center something in HTML and CSS, your two simplest options are:

- Full-width container with `text-align: center`
- Full-width container, children with `display: block;margin: 0 auto;`

The first gives you a container wherein all children will be centered by the typesetting algorithm. This generally works well and is pretty simple, but centers all children, so doesn't work for all use cases.

The second gives you a child that will be on its own line (`display: block`), which will center itself in its parent using equal margins on either side to fill any empty width in the parent (`margin: 0 auto` gives zero top/bottom margin and auto left/right margin).

In your example code, you could use:

```
.col-md-6 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
```

}

Which centers the lines containing the search boxes; however, because the search *buttons* are different widths, the overall effect is a little off. You could either put each line (search box + button) in a container with a fixed width, or you could give the buttons a fixed with large enough for the largest one; or you could put the buttons and search boxes on separate lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap, you can add the class `col-md-offset-3` to your div tag and all content wrapped in that div tag will be centered in the page.
And if searchbars and clickboxes aren't in a line, set margin-top to zero for clickbox class.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand you properly but try with text-align: center on form.

Answer (score -2):

In html, you can use the center tag.